# bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect on a sprite

Tags: ios7, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I want to create several boxes that will include sprites inside, let's say squares. The squares will bounce inside the boxes borders. For that purpose I used bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect for each box. Why I'm using bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect instead of creating a physical body? Because I want the squares inside the box to be confined and to bounce inside only. If I create a physical body the squares will collide from the outside.

I created a [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:] for every box but the squares just left the boxes as there were no physical body inside.
It seems that bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect only works for the scene SKNode physics node: self.physicsBody

I checked the documentation for the bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect method and I found no mention that it must be used only on a scene object. It seems that it can be used on any SKNode.

This is the code. The white squares inside just fall down by gravity. They don't bounce inside the black boxes as I think they should.

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -0.2);
self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:self.frame];
SKSpriteNode *boxContainer01 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
boxContainer01.position = CGPointMake(boxContainer01.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);
SKSpriteNode *boxContainer02 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
boxContainer02.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width - boxContainer01.size.width/2, self.size.height/2);

boxContainer01.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:boxContainer01.frame];
boxContainer02.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:boxContainer02.frame];
boxContainer01.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
boxContainer02.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
SKSpriteNode *square01 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
square01.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:square01.size];
square01.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
SKSpriteNode *square02 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor whiteColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 20)];
square02.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:square02.size];
square02.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;

[boxContainer01 addChild:square01];
[boxContainer02 addChild:square02];

[self addChild:boxContainer01];
[self addChild:boxContainer02];
self.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1;
```

[image: Squares ignore the physics body]
[image: Squares hit the borders of the screen]

Comment: please state your problem more clearly - what do you expect to happen and what is actually happening? "it doesn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it wasn't clear. I edited the comment again with a better explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code fragment you posted is complete regarding the setup of the physics, then what you are missing is to set the `contactTestBitMask` of the bodies. By default its value is 0 which means bodies don't contact (and as a consequence: don't collide) with other bodies unless the bitmask is changed.

Try giving all your bodies the same contact test bitmask, like for instance:

```
node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1;
```

This will make those bodies whose contactTestBitMask matches (more precise: when a logical AND comparison between two body's contactTestBitMask values results in a non-zero value) they will contact and collide.

Comment: I did but the squares still ignore the physics body of the boxes. I updated the code and I uploaded a couple of screenshots to show what's going on. The code looks correct, I really can't figure out why the squares just ignore the boxes. Even if the collisionBitMask is 1 by default, I just added it to show that they should collide.

Comment: Propably it's not cover your sprite and it's appear in othe rplace on the screen. bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect
check if its corectly around your sprite.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I finally found the answer to this. I was hitting a stumbling block over this as well, and used the code from Apple's spritekit programming guide to generate falling rocks to see if the physics body happened to be created elsewhere. My box was in the center of the screen, but the falling rocks hit an invisible block to the upper right of the screen, so it seemed that the bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect was trying to recalculate the origin when creating the physicsbody. In Apple's documentation for bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect it says:

> rect: The rectangle that defines the edges. The rectangle is specified
>   relative to the owning node’s origin.

I believe that what is happening is that when you change the position of the box, you are changing it in the coordinate system of the parent node. When you add a physics body, you are doing so in the coordinate space of the box itself. When you first create the box, the coordinate system of the parent node and the box are aligned, but as soon as you move the box, they are not the same.

So, the easiest solution is to create your physics body for your boxes frame BEFORE you set the box position. Doing so will allow you them to align correctly when you reposition it. Either that, or change your physics body to this (this correctly sets the origin since the anchorpoint is automatically in the center of box):

```
boxContainer01.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(-boxContainer01.frame.size.width/2, -boxContainer01.frame.size.height/2, boxContainer01.frame.size.width, boxContainer01.frame.size.height)];
```